# Jenkins sometimes takes JUnit @Ignore tag into account, sometimes not?

Tags: junit, jenkins

I have added @Ignore tag to some test classes (class level, not method level). Some of these test classes with @Ignore tag are now ignored by Jenkins (correct), but some classes with @Ignore tag are still executed. Mind you, even those test classes executed do not actually execute any tests because all tests have been commented away, but Jenkins gives "initialization error" which is a sign that there are no tests to execute. How is this possible? The test classes are normal unit tests, and look to be pretty much identical.

Comment: What kind of tests are executed? Methods in ignored classes? Whole ignored classes? Something else?

Comment: Could you give an example of such incorrectly executed test class? Is this behaviour consistent? Is it just Jenkins? Have you tried in Maven/Eclipse/etc?

Comment: I am sorry, I realized I was very vague in my post. I have edited my original post. The tests executed are normal unit tests. All test method have been commented away, therefore the Ignore tag has been placed on class level. The behavior is consistent in Jenkins. Eclipse does not let me execute the test class because it has no test methods (commented away) and the Ignore tag has been placed on class level.

Answer (score 0):

try using the @Ignore tag at the method level instead of the class level.